# Iterating through and 'selecting' jQuery DataTables rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.3 to create a table with JSON data fetched from a web service.  The data is linked to other elements on the page of my application such that when a user selects data points in one element, the DataTable should update and 'select' the complimentary rows (simply by adding the `active` class to the rows `<tr>` tag).  Given the [documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()), it would appear that this could be easily accomplished with something like this:

```
var table = $("#my-table").DataTable();
table.rows().each(function(r){
    if (r.data().category == 'XYZ'){
        r.node().to$().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

But this does not work, since `.rows()` returns an array of row indexes instead of row objects.  Instead, I have implemented this:

```
var table = $("#my-table").DataTable();
table.rows().indexes().each(function(i){
    var r = table.row(i);
    if (r.data().category == 'XYZ'){
        r.node().to$().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

This works, but is incredibly slow, considering the relatively small number of records in the table (~3 seconds for 3000 rows).  Is there a better way to iterate through DataTable rows that I am missing?  Or is it possible to make a row selection based on data values?  Are the documents incorrect about `.rows()` returning API objects?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an answer to my second question:

> Or is it possible to make a row selection based on data values?

```
var table = $("#my-table").DataTable();
table.rows(function(idx, data, node){
    return data.category == 'XYZ' ? true: false;
}).nodes().to$().addClass("active");
```

This run almost instantly, so it handles my use case, but I'd still like to know what the best way is to iterate through rows in a more general way.